# python pandas - change values in column A based on column B which contains lists of strings

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

How can I change the values in the "Comedy" column based on if the corresponding "genres" column value (list) contains "Comedy"?

The result in the "Comedy" column should be

```
True
False
True
True
True
```

I have tried everything fron .isin, .contains, .find etc.

Note: Originally the values in the "genres" column looked like

```
Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
```

but I split them using

```
df["genres"] = df.genres.str.split("|")
```

[image: dataframe example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
                           genres
0  [Adventure, Animation, Comedy]
1               [Fantasy, Horror]
2                 [Comedy, Drama]
3                           [nan]
4                             NaN

In [98]: df['Comedy'] = df.genres.fillna('').apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & set(['Comedy'])) == 1)

In [99]: df
Out[99]:
                           genres  Comedy
0  [Adventure, Animation, Comedy]    True
1               [Fantasy, Horror]   False
2                 [Comedy, Drama]    True
3                           [nan]   False
4                             NaN   False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `in` parameter with `apply` if have `list` columns, for replace `NaN`s add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df["genres"] = df.genres.str.split("|")
df['new'] = df['genres'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: 'Comedy' in x)
print (df)
                                              genres    new
0  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fantasy]   True
1                     [Adventure, Children, Fantasy]  False
2                                  [Comedy, Romance]   True
3                           [Comedy, Drama, Romance]   True
4                                           [Comedy]   True
5                                                NaN  False
```

Thanks [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674143/python-pandas-change-values-in-column-a-based-on-column-b-which-contains-lists/45674161#comment78305722_45674161) for solution:

```
df['new'] = ['Comedy' in x for x in df['genres']]
```

Without `list` use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with parameter `na=False`:

```
df['new'] = df['genres'].str.contains('Comedy', na=False)
print (df)
                                        genres    new
0  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy   True
1                   Adventure|Children|Fantasy  False
2                               Comedy|Romance   True
3                         Comedy|Drama|Romance   True
4                                       Comedy   True
5                                          NaN  False
```

Comment: Or, `df['new'] = ['Comedy' in x for x in df['genres']]`

Comment: For some reason this gives me an error:  "TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable". Maybe it has to do with the note in my question (added with edit).

Comment: @PerryPrunesquallor - Problem is some `NaN`s values